# Link to index with default {_locale} parameter

Tags: symfony-2.1

I have a language selector in my project to redirect to index page with the locale parameter {_locale}, but when the link is to default locale seted in routing.yml, the link looks different. This is my code:

I generate the link in code:

```
<a href="{{ path('ProjectBaseBundle_index', {'_locale': country.idlang}) }}">
    ...
</a>
```

And here is the routing.yml:

```
ProjectBaseBundle_index:
    pattern:  /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:index, _locale: es }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|de|es
```

This generate propertly the routes for all languages, buy for the default one looks different:

```
http://project.dev/app_dev.php/en
http://project.dev/app_dev.php/fr
http://project.dev/app_dev.php/de
http://project.dev/app_dev.php/?_locale=es
```

*es* is our default language code. I'm using Symfony 2.1

**Anyone know How to generate identical route for the default lang?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that it makes sense, because the parameter {_locale} does not exists for the default language, so the system appended the parameter as a GET parameter.

I found a workaround:

```
ProjectBaseBundle_default:
    pattern: /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:index , _locale: %locale% }

ProjectBaseBundle_index:
    pattern: /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBaseBundle:Default:index }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|de|es
```

and I have opened a issue in Symfony board: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5135

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of conditions for requirements and provided parameters in [`UrlGenerator`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L201) - unknown parameters passed through the arguments array are automatically appended at the end of the URL as GET parameters.

Did you try to put default locale in `config.yml` **instead of** having it in `defaults` section of route?

**Symfony-2.0**:

```
framework:
    session: { default_locale: es }
```

**Symfony-2.1**:

```
framework:
    default_locale: es
```

Comment: Yes, I have it defined. Why the others languages works fine? it is the same situation. If I use other language as default in routing.yml, it's happend with this other language

Comment: @Ztere0 Which version of Syfmony do you use? 2.0 or 2.1?

Comment: Symfony 2.1, sorry I do not mentioned in the post

Comment: Updated my answer. Have you tried to set default_locale as it is defined for 2.1?

Comment: Yes, yes.. I have default_locale is defined as Symfony2.1 config

Comment: Really interesting issue... Is it possible that `country.idlang` contains `null`? Let's create chat may be? :)

Comment: no, idlang is 'es' value. It is really strange the behavior. If in few days anyone know something about maybe I will open a issue in Symfony2 tracker.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce an issue... Looks that `_locale` is not counted as `defaults` in routing. Can you try to remove it? Since you have default_locale set in framework - no need to put it as `defaults` in route

Comment: I have tried with '_locale: %locale%' and deleting the default value, just using { _controller: ReforestalBaseBundle:Default:index }. With locale = %locale% he behavior is the same, without parameter I get an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14643/discussion-between-ztere0-and-thecatontheflat)